Segmentation fault in al_draw_filled_rectangle
I created a simple program that just draws a black square on a blue background to make sure everything works and is installed correctly:
// g++ -I "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\" test.cpp -o test.exe -g -lallegro -lallegro_primitives
#include <allegro5/allegro5.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    al_init();
    
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* d = al_create_display(256, 256);
    
    if (d == NULL)
        std::cout << "Error in initializing display" << std::endl;
    
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 255));
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(64, 64, 192, 192, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
    al_flip_display();
    
    al_rest(30);
    
    al_destroy_display(d);
    al_uninstall_system();
    return 0;
}

...but when I try to run it with gdb .\test.exe it returns this error:
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
al_lock_mutex (mutex=0x0) at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/src/threads.c:325
warning: 325    C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/src/threads.c: No such file or directory

Here's the full stack trace:
#0  al_lock_mutex (mutex=0x0) at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/src/threads.c:325
#1  0x00007ffc351282bc in get_display_local_data (display=display@entry=0x616fa0)
    at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/addons/primitives/prim_directx.cpp:138
#2  0x00007ffc35129a4b in draw_prim_raw (target=0x617280, texture=0x0, vtx=0x5ffd90, decl=0x0, indices=0x0, num_vtx=4,
    type=5) at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/addons/primitives/prim_directx.cpp:500
#3  0x00007ffc3512a011 in _al_draw_prim_directx (target=target@entry=0x617280, texture=texture@entry=0x0,
    vtxs=vtxs@entry=0x5ffd90, decl=decl@entry=0x0, start=<optimized out>, start@entry=0, end=<optimized out>,
    end@entry=4, type=<optimized out>, type@entry=5)
    at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/addons/primitives/prim_directx.cpp:656
#4  0x00007ffc3512e048 in al_draw_prim (vtxs=0x5ffd90, decl=0x0, texture=0x0, start=0, end=4, type=5)
    at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/addons/primitives/primitives.c:104
#5  0x00007ffc35122784 in al_draw_filled_rectangle (x1=<optimized out>, y1=0, x2=<optimized out>, y2=0, color=...)
    at C:/dev/allegro_winpkg/universal/allegro/addons/primitives/high_primitives.c:422
#6  0x00007ff7a78f1553 in main (argc=1, argv=0xf61b60) at test.cpp:16

I'm guessing there's some sort of step I missed in the setup process of mingw, but I don't know how to fix it. Anyone have any answers?

When you catch the crash in your debugger, go up the call-stack until you get to your own code. Where in your program does the crash happen?

@Someprogrammerdude the crash happens when I try to set the background color to blue here: al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 255));

al_create_display returns NULL on error. Did you check for errors?

@Botje yes, al_create_display is working fine. The window shows up like normal, but the program crashes immediately after.

OT: You seem to include more header files than needed. Considering the quickstart example all you should need would be <allegro5/allegro5.h>. Note that this should be unrelated to the problem you have.

@Someprogrammerdude oh right, sorry about that. I copied some code from a previous program I made in Linux, so I guess I forgot to check which headers were needed and which ones weren't.

Can you edit your question with a full stack trace? (bt in gdb)

The call to al_draw_filled_rectangle in the stack-trace looks suspekt... Both y1 and y2 as zero? While the x coordinates are "optimized out"? Are you sure you're building and running the code you think your building and running? Especially since you now have modified the code in the question, and the call to al_draw_filled_rectangle is no longer on line 18 (as it is in the call-stack). When you build, type type test.cpp (or cat test.cpp) to look at the file you build, is it the correct one? How do you run the program?

@Someprogrammerdude sorry, I updated the code in response to some previous comments, and forgot to change the question to reflect this. I've double checked to make sure it is the right file.

Looks like you're missing al_init_primitives_addon() to initialize the primitives addon.

@ssbssa That seems to have solved it! Thank you so much!

When if (d == NULL) is true (btw, why do you use NULL and not nullptr in a modern C++ program?) you just print an error message and then continue on as if nothing bad happened, why?

On my Linux system, your program works fine, but for Windows you might need to call (as said in comment):
al_init_primitives_addon();

before you can use a function such as al_draw_filled_rectangle.
